# Ignoring of negative values from Java Arraylist for calculations

Tags: java, arraylist, negative-number

The idea of my code is that it asks user the income of each month, until the user imputs negative value, which should not be added to the total income and which should be shown in output, but ignored in calculations.
Then the code calculates the total income (ignoring the last negative value), the average income (ignoring the negative value) and the biggest/maximum value of all values. I don't have problems getting right that maximum value. But how could I ignore the negative income in calculations, and maby even not to add it at all to the array?

The problem is that the calculation adds also the negative value/income to the total sum and average income calculations. And it does not ignore the month of the negative income.

Here is my code so far:

```
package income;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Income {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int months = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write the income of each month.");

         ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         System.out.println("Write the income of month 1: ");
            int income = input.nextInt();
            sum += income;
            months++;
            array.add(income);

        while(true){
            months++;
            System.out.println("Write " + months + ". month income: ");
            if(income >= 0){
            income = input.nextInt();
            sum += income;

            array.add(income);

            }
            else if (income < 0){
                break;
            }
        }

        /*This did not work
          for(int i= 0; i < array.size(); i++){
              if(income < 0){
                  array.remove(i);
              }
          }*/
        months--;

        System.out.println("The total income is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average income is " + sum/months);

        //This one below works fine
        System.out.println("The biggest income is " + Collections.max(array));
        } 
    }
```

Comment: why do you even need to add the last negative value to the list?

Comment: The idea is that when I add the negative value, it does not asks more values anymore and calculates and prints these things: the total income, the average income and the maximum income.

Comment: do you need the negative value for any calculations at all?

Comment: I don't want to add the negative value to the list, but don't know how to avoid it successfully. I need the array list for the use of Collections framework. I don't need the negative value for calculations at all.

Comment: If you don't care about the negative value for anything other than as a stopper, you can just invert the if condition and not add the value to the list at all.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. I have tried not to add the negative income, but it adds it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are indeed adding the last negative number into account in the calculations, this is not the ultimate reason why your code is not working. You are actually checking whether the *previous* input you read is greater than 0 here:

```
while(true){
    months++;
    System.out.println("Write " + months + ". month income: ");
    if(income >= 0){ <------
    income = input.nextInt();
```

So the loop will only stop if the *previous* input is less than 0. In other words, when you enter e.g. `-1` in, the input is not checked until the next iteration of the loop, at which point `-1` has already been added to the array. Therefore, you should instead check `income >= 0` *immediately after* `nextInt`:

```
System.out.println("Write the income of each month.");
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
while(true){
    months++;
    System.out.println("Write the income for month" + months + ":");
    int income = input.nextInt();
    if(income >= 0){
        sum += income;

        array.add(income);

    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that I've also removed the bit between `Write the income of each month.` and the `while` loop, as it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you are looking for.

```
    var list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    var in = new Scanner(System.in);
    var i = 0;

    System.out.println("Write Income of Each Month.");

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Write " + ++i + ".month income : " );
        int num = in.nextInt();

        if (num < 0)
        {
            int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
            double avg = (double) sum / --i;
            int max = Collections.max(list);

            System.out.printf("Sum : %d\nAverage : %f\nBiggest Number : %d\nNegative No. %d", sum ,avg, max, num);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            list.add(num);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Integer.signum(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum(int)) function to know whether the value is negative (returned value = -1) or zero (returned value = 0) or positive (returned value = 1). So, basically ignore `if Integer.signum(income) == -1`